# Collocation I wanna know if these are English collocations.Is this usage correct?

Tags: grammar

I wd like to know if the following collocations exist in English language. The non native speakers often use the phrases
1.give answer for ( to answer) 
2.give respect for (to respect)

Please clarify

Comment: If you are looking for pointers on speaking English, you should be aware that "wanna" is extremely informal and almost never used in "proper" written English. The most common example I can think of is using the word "wanna-be" as a noun.

Comment: Also, "wd" may be appropriate for texting with friends, but not so much for writing to be read by strangers. Use "would" instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "give an answer" to answer someone by giving them some information they asked for or describing your answer. for example:

```
I didn't give him a straight answer.
```

"give your respects to somebody" it's a kind of polite greeting:

```
give my respects to your father.
```